# [Macromedia][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]ORA-04054: database link does not exist

Tags: oracle, coldfusion

I am trying to create a simple login page with ColdFusion however I've been running into error ORA-04054. Regardless of which value I give my #FORM.login_password# value my app tries to connect to #FORM.login_password#.server.com so if I try to login with

login_email = "test@test.test"

login_password = "test"

ColdFusion will try to connect to test.server.com and return an error. I initially thought that this would be due to multiple variables having conflicting names however after renaming all my variables countless times I've run out of ideas.

FORM:

```
<form action="login.cfm" method="post">
    E-mail: <input type="email" name="login_email" required placeholder="E-mail">
    Password: <input type="password" name="login_password" required placeholder="Password">
    <input name="submit" type="submit" Value="Search Parts">
</form>
```

LOGIN.CFM:

```
<cfinclude template="header.cfm">
<cfinclude template="base.cfm">
<cfquery name="*****"
datasource="*****"
username="*****"
password="*****">
SELECT *
FROM tbUser
WHERE password = #FORM.login_password#
AND email = #FORM.login_email#
</cfquery>
<cfoutput>
    <cfif #userLogin.RecordCount# eq 0>
        FAILURE
    <cfelse>
        SUCCESS
    </cfif>
</cfoutput>


<cfinclude template="footer.cfm">
```

Comment: According to this, http://ora-04054.ora-code.com/, you are trying to connect to a database that does not exist.  I suggest taking the username and password attributes out of your cfquery tag and verifying your datascource on your ColdFusion admin page.

Comment: I understand that however if I don't put any WHERE clause my query selects everything from tbUser. There is no problem with my datasource, username or password since I'm using them in other pages with no problem.

Comment: I believe that Dan was referring the the usename/password for the DB connect. That username/password is different from the one stored in tbUser

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you should parameterize your WHERE clause using `cfqueryparam`, other wise, the login is susceptible to SQL injection.

Comment: Use QUOTES in your SQL for STRINGS! :)

Comment: No use CFQUERYPARAM for your string parameters! ;-) And your numbers, dates, lions, tigers and bears too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer, despite eluding me for so long, was pretty simple in the end: I hadn't encapsulated my query values in quotes:

```
    <cfquery name="*****" datasource="*****" username="*****" password="*****">
        SELECT *
        FROM tbUser
        WHERE password = '#FORM.login_password#'
        AND email = '#FORM.login_email#'
    </cfquery>

    <cfif userLogin.RecordCount eq 0>
        FAILURE
    <cfelse>
        SUCCESS
    </cfif>
```

Comment: The Oracle database was likely reading the @data as a symbolic link.

Answer (score 2):

You should use cfqueryparam. It's a best practice and I think solve the problem.
Like that:

```
and email = <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.login_email#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
```

Comment: True, though it should be used on both parameters ie `login_email` and `login_password`